# How long may I stay in Israel after my A2 visa expires?

Tags: israel, overstaying

My A2 student visa will be expired by 7th dec. I would leave Israel by 12th dec. May I stay in Israel these days without visa. Is there any difficulties I will face during my departure time?

Comment: Are you asking may you physically or may you legally?

Answer (score 3):

No. You need to extend your visa by visiting the Ministry of the Interior (Misrad Hapnim).